# pass variable to cells.find and cell address as result in vba

Tags: excel, find, cells, vba

How can i pass a variable to cells.find and get the cell address as result back?

```
 For Each cellName In activeListBoxelements

    Cells.Find(What:=cellName, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

    CellAddr = Selection.Address(False, False, xlR1C1)

    MsgBox (CellAddr)
Next cellName
```

What am i doing wrong here.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the `.Find` is returning anything and then display the address.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Dim aCell As Range, cellName As Range, activeListBoxelements As Range
Dim CellAddr As String

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'

For Each cellName In activeListBoxelements
    Set aCell = Cells.Find(What:=cellName.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                           SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> Check if found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        CellAddr = aCell.Address(False, False, xlR1C1)
        MsgBox CellAddr
        Set aCell = Nothing
    End If
Next cellName
```